# Ajustar buttons en Grid.Column Xamarin Form c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.forms

Hola Comunidad tengo un grid.colum->ScrollView->FlexLayout -> dentro del flex agrego dinamicamente buttons, lo que intento hacer que se ajusten en todo el espacio

XAML

```
 <Grid Grid.Column="1">
   <ScrollView>
       <FlexLayout x:Name="sl"
          Wrap="Wrap"
            JustifyContent="SpaceBetween" /> 
    </ScrollView>
</Grid>
```

.CS

```
Button button = new Button{
 VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
 HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
};
```

Captura (Grid.Column) Aqui deseo que se expandan, y no dejen espacios.
Alguien podria ayudarme?gracias!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si quieres que todos los botones se vean parejos no uses el `FlexLayout` cambialo por el `StackLayout`, con este veras los controles uno debajo del otro pudiendo lograr que sean del mismo ancho

[Xamarin.Forms StackLayout](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/stack-layout)

Entonces si al usar el `LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand` tomara todo el espacio

---

Sino la alternativa usando el [FlexLayout](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/flex-layout) seria ver si definiendo

[FlexLayout.Direction Property](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.flexlayout.direction?view=xamarin-forms#Xamarin_Forms_FlexLayout_Direction)

asignando esta como `Column` entiendo tambien deberia aplicar

```
 <FlexLayout x:Name="sl"
         Direction="Column" />
```

Analiza los ejemplos

[FlexLayout Demos](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/UserInterface/FlexLayoutDemos/)

Comment: Gracias, me funciono reemplazar FlexLayout por StackLayout.